# How can I change div content with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have simple HTML code with some JavaScript. It looks like:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function changeDivContent() { // ...
    };
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="A" onClick="changeDivContent()">
  <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="B" onClick="changeDivContent()">

  <div id="content"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

I just wanted to be able to change the div's content (it's inner html) with selecting one of "A" or "B" radio buttons, but div#content does not have javascript attribute "value", so I am asking how it can be done.

Answer (score 572, accepted):

Assuming you're not using jQuery or some other library that makes this sort of thing easier for you, you can just use the element's innerHTML property.

```
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = "whatever";
```

Comment: **Warning!** the usage of `innerHTML` can easily lead to XSS vulnerabilities when the value comes from an untrusted input.

The use of `innerText` is always recommended for security reasons and currently it is supported by all browsers (https://caniuse.com/#feat=innertext)

Answer (score 33):

Using jQuery:

```
$('#content').html('whatever');
```

Comment: Thanks for this was trying to use replace_html but this seemed to fix my issue. Any idea why?

Comment: This is jQuery solution.

Answer (score 18):

you can use following helper function:

```
function content(divSelector, value) {
    document.querySelector(divSelector).innerHTML = value;
}

content('#content',"whatever");
```

Where `#content` must be valid [CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)

Here is [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/n6q3d5mj/3/).

---

Additionaly - today (2018.07.01) I made speed comparison for jquery and pure js solutions ( MacOs High Sierra 10.13.3 on Chrome 67.0.3396.99 (64-bit), Safari 11.0.3 (13604.5.6), Firefox 59.0.2 (64-bit) ):

```
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = "whatever"; // pure JS
$('#content').html('whatever');                            // jQuery
```

[image]

The jquery solution was slower than pure js solution: 69% on firefox, 61% on safari, 56% on chrome. The fastest browser for pure js was firefox with 560M operations per second, the second was safari 426M, and slowest was chrome 122M.

**So the winners are pure js and firefox** (3x faster than chrome!)

You can test it in your machine: https://jsperf.com/js-jquery-html-content-change

Answer (score 4):

change onClick to `onClick="changeDivContent(this)"` and try

```
function changeDivContent(btn) {
  content.innerHTML = btn.value
}
```

```js
function changeDivContent(btn) {
  content.innerHTML = btn.value
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="A" onClick="changeDivContent(this)">
<input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="B" onClick="changeDivContent(this)">

<div id="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="A" onclick = "populateData(event)">
  <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="B" onclick = "populateData(event)">

    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

-----------------JS- code------------

```
var targetDiv = document.getElementById('content');
    var htmlContent = '';

    function populateData(event){
      switch(event.target.value){
        case 'A':{
         htmlContent = 'Content for A';
          break;
        }
        case 'B':{
          htmlContent = "content for B";
break;
        }
      }
      targetDiv.innerHTML = htmlContent;
    }
```

---

```
Step1: on click of the radio button it calls function populate data, with event (an object that has event details such as name of the element, value etc..);

Step2: I extracted the value through event.target.value and then simple switch will give me freedom to add custom text.
```

---

Live Code

https://jsbin.com/poreway/edit?html,js,output