# change html contents via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I change the contents of my paragraph as well as the contents of my list once the link was clicked. reference: http://dummyproto.atspace.co.uk/

once i click woven badges on the navigation carousel i want to change the contents of the p as well as the imaged displayed. Is that possible via javascript? Is it a great alternative rather than creating a bunch of html pages for every page which has the same layout but different contents.

I'm looking forward to detailed solutions.Thanks

Comment: Probably what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554149/html-javascript-change-div-content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I'd make a `div` "card" for each of your carousel options containing any images or text you want to go with them. Then I'd set all of them but the first to `display: none;`. When another link in the carousel is clicked, I'd cycle through the "cards," setting them all to `display: none` except the one needed (which should have the same number in the order of cards as the carousel item you selected in the order of carousel items), which will be `display: block;` so that I don't have to store HTML into Javascript variables.

Comment: thanks. I think this is the simplest solution and still works out perfectly. i'll be sticking to div styling.

Answer (score 3):

You need to modify your HTML a bit first so the content you want to swap out is contained in a single element that is easily selectable (for example wrap a div with a unique class name or id around just the stuff you want to swap out). Then do something like this:

```
document.getElementById('whateverIdYouGaveTheDiv').innerHTML = "blah blah blah";
```

Comment: thats fine with p element but how can i execute that if i would change this <li><a class="zoomThumbActive" href='javascript:void(0);' rel="{gallery: 'gal1', smallimage: 'UniwinView.jpg',largeimage: 'Uniwin.jpg'}"><img src='uniwinThumb.jpg'></a></li> I have to change the small image,largeimage and the img.

Comment: I guess you would put it in a function and then call that function instead of doing nothing where you have `javascript:void(0);` ... although generally I think using the `javascript:`  URI scheme is considered bad form...

Comment: ah.well i just got that from a jqzoom plugin. i just keep tweaking them. do you know how can i do the function for it?

Answer (score 2):

maybe you can try [jQuery template](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.template).

or, change the html when the trigger is clicked by using `.click()` and `.html()`

like:

```
var target_html = "something you want";

$('#trigger').click(function() {
    $("#content").html(target_html);
});
```

Comment: i think doing that will just be the same as linking the page and  still i have to create a bunch of html pages. isnt it?

Comment: I just checked your site, i think, query template is perfect to you. you can write all your content into a JSON object, and render them by the template engine.