# Change the value of a div

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following code with which I can change the value of a button while pressing on it:

HTML:

```
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Register"/>
```

jQuery:

```
$(":submit").click(function() {
    $("#test").attr("value", "please wait...");
});
```

I however would like to change the text in a div when pressing a button. So i have:

```
<body>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Register"/>
    <div id="test"> </div>
</body>
```

And would like to change the div from `""` to `please...` wait by pressing the submit button:

```
$(":submit").click(function() {
    $("#test").attr("value", "please wait...");
});
```

This does not work however. Anybody have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML/Javascript change div content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554149/html-javascript-change-div-content)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use **[.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)**:

```
$(":submit").click(function() {
     $("#test").text("please wait...");
});
```

or **[.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)** instead:

```
$(":submit").click(function() {
     $("#test").html("please wait...");
});
```

since `<div>` does not have value, it only has content so `.text()` or `.html()` will help you to change the content of `<div>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

```
$(":submit").click(function() {
$("#test").text("please wait...");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
   <script>   
       function f(){   
           document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "whatever";
       }
   </script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="f()"/>
<input type="submit" value="Register"/>

<div id="test"> </div>


</body>
```