# change div content and refresh div when press keyboard key

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `div` with images. I want to hide those images when I press key on key board. How can I do that?

```html
<div>
    <span role="checkbox" aria-checked="true" tabindex="0">
        <img src="checked.gif" role="presentation" alt="" />
        
    </span>
    </div>
    <div>
    <span role="checkbox" aria-checked="true" tabindex="0">
        <img src="checked.gif" role="presentation" alt="" />
        
    </span>
    </div>
    <div>
    <span role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" tabindex="0">
        <img src="unchecked.gif" role="presentation" alt="" />
      
    </span>
    </div>
```

This is `div` with content. I want to hide these images on `keypress` event..!

Comment: With javascript

Comment: You need javascript for that. There are multiple questions that should help you to solve your problem. Such as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16089470/2412895) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554149/html-javascript-change-div-content) ect

Comment: HTML is for content, CSS is for styling, Javascript is for interactivity. You've got HTML, now you need Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listen for `keyup` event and than `.hide()` elements.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('body').keyup(function () {
    $('.img').fadeToggle();
    //$('.img').hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span role="checkbox" aria-checked="true" tabindex="0" class="img">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/" role="presentation" alt="" />
  </span>
</div>
<div>
  <span role="checkbox" aria-checked="true" tabindex="0" class="img">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/" role="presentation" alt="" />
  </span>
</div>
<div>
  <span role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" tabindex="0" class="img">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/" role="presentation" alt="" />
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: i think i got the point from you. thank you.

Comment: What the problem with that code is, that the animation gets queued when you spam a key. So it continues to fade in and out after you stopped pressing a key. You can fix that simpy by adding `stop()`. So line 3 of your JS looks like this: `$('.img').stop().fadeToggle();`

Answer (score 0):

Try with `keypress` event

```js
$(document).on('keypress',function(){
$('img').hide()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<span role="checkbox" aria-checked="true" tabindex="0">
    <img src="checked.gif" role="presentation" alt="" />

</span>
</div>
<div>
<span role="checkbox" aria-checked="true" tabindex="0">
    <img src="checked.gif" role="presentation" alt="" />

</span>
</div>
<div>
<span role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" tabindex="0">
    <img src="unchecked.gif" role="presentation" alt="" />

</span>
</div>
```

Comment: wow.. its worked.