# The html interface just disappear after the first use and throw me some errors

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a little game on html about random numbers, you have to try to get a number between 45 and 55, and you can try more than one number at once (1-5), but it will make numbers variate more, for example:

Got 33, 65, 12, 89. The player did 4 attempts so:

> **33 + random{-1,1} * (random[1,3] ** 4)** *(this with each number)*

numbers are stored in `nums`. After created, they are modified, and then, a "filter" will check if some of them are between 45 and 55, if so, that numbers are pushed inside `winner` and shown. A different pup up will appear if there is no winning number.

---

### The problem:

When try it on Dcoder the interface will just disappear and console will throw me some errors.

**PS:** I dedicated a few lines of code to create a log, to make sure if everything was ok with the numbers, this helped me a lot fixing something without having to ask someone, but this time it escaped off from my hands and knowledge.

> 81 added
>   53 added
>   90 modified
>   54 modified
>   90 rejected
>   54 approved
>   54
>   Uncaught ReferenceError: start is not defined
>   Uncaught ReferenceError: onHasParentDirectory is not defined
>   Uncaught ReferenceError: addRow is not defined
>   Uncaught ReferenceError: addRow is not defined
>   Uncaught ReferenceError: addRow is not defined

Another question, I want to put a counter of: Times played, Total amount of attempts, winning attempts, losing attempts. In a text on the page, how to make text variate based on the value of a `var` in the js code?

```js
function GtData() {
   var r = [Number(document.getElementById("amAtt").value)];
   return r
}

function Evt() {
   var Data = GtData();
   if (1 <= Data && Data <= 5) {
      var nums = [];
      for (i = 0; i < Data; i++) {
         nums.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 101));
         console.log(nums[i] + " added");
      }
      var coef = Math.round(Math.random());
      var soa = 0;
      if (coef == 1) {
         soa++
      }
      else {
         soa--
      }
      for (i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
         nums[i] += soa * (Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 1) ** Data);
         console.log(nums[i] + " modified");
      }
      var winner = [];
      for (i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
         if (45 <= nums[i] && nums[i] <= 55) {
            winner.push(nums[i]);
            console.log(nums[i] + " approved");
         }
         else {
            console.log(nums[i] + " rejected");
         }
      }
      var r = winner;
      console.log(r);
      if (r.length != 0) {
         window.alert("We got a winner: " + r + " !");
      }
      else {
         window.alert("No luck boy...");
      }
   }
}
```

```css
.center {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 8px double;
}
.button {
  display = "block";
}
```

```html
<html>
   <head> 
   </head>
   <body>
      <form>
         <p class="center">Amount of attempts!<br>
         <input type="number" class="center" id="amAtt" placeholder="1 - 5" min="1" max="5" required=""><br>
         <input type="submit" class="center" onclick="Evt()"></p>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your HTML disappears is because you wrapped your code in `<form>`
and form will automatically reload the page.

To resolve it, change:

```
<input type="submit" class="center" onclick="Evt()"></p>
```

to:

```
event.preventDefault(), Evt()
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp

Comment: Can you answer my second question? Thx for helping me!

Comment: Let say you have `<div id="results"></div>`

You can update the value of this div with `document.querySelector("#results").innerHTML = \`
total attempts: ${attempts}
total attempts: ${winningAttempts}
total attempts: ${loosingAttempts}
\``

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554149/html-javascript-change-div-content